# InstallAware 9 problem with Paradox DB and Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, paradox, installaware

My project is on Delphi 2009, Paradox DB and Google Maps. The code is OK and the time right now is to build the project. This is the first time to do it. As I know there are two programs to create the setup file; InstallShield or InstallAware. Via InstallAware I did my first test but its fail and the problem is the DB, I could not run it after the setup. How can I make the DB work in setup file.

In my delphi project there is two part for DB connections;

```
the first one with;  Query1--->DataScore1
the second one; Table1--->Datascore2
```

the root of delphi files is "Desktop\ttelekom\ttelekom.exe
the root of DB files is "C:\Program Files\Common Files\CodeGear Shared\Data\databasettelekom.db"

Here the picture of Delphi main form;
http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/5333/77714402.png

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

How are you accessing the database? If it's using the BDE, you have to install the BDE. There's a merge module you can add to your installation, by default in `%CommonProgramFiles%\Borland Shared\BDE\` - read the `bdedeploy.txt` file you'll find there, along with `bdeinst.txt`.

If you're using another way to access the Paradox files (for instance, ODBC), you'll have to configure that instead.

Answer (score 1):

asilloo, when you said `"..As I know there are two programs to create the setup file.."` that is not true, exist many options to create installers like [wise](http://www.wise.com/Products/Installations/WiseInstallationStudio.aspx), [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), [Inno-setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

for you specific task i will you recommend Inno-setup, because is freeware, reliable, easy to learn and the script language used to create the installers is delphi.

to deploy your application do you need install the bde in client machine. check this sample using inno-setup.

- Inno Setup Knowledge Base - [HOWTO: Deploy BDE (Borland Database Engine)](http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?bde)